# Rackspace Image exporting with curl

Tags: image, curl, rackspace

Like to download an Image from rackspace but to do that I have to work with curl :-S

https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/t/3583

What I understood is that I have to install curll on my rackspace server. Now I can login with the terminal , thereby, I can do basic things , but how do I setup the Step #0: Setup your environment variables? as in the document requested..

Johan.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial all about *nix environment variables: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/

In short:

> How Do I Make All Settings permanent?
>
> The `~/.bash_profile` (`$HOME/.bash_profile`) or `~/.profile` file is
>   executed when you login using console or remotely using ssh. Type the
>   following command to edit `~/.bash_profile` file, enter:
>
> `nano  ~/.bash_proflle`
>
> Append the $PATH settings, enter:
>
> `export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/bin`